# Loot bonus during war

Tags: clash-of-clans

Hi my clan mate has the same townhall as I do, just a little more level 10 walls. During war he always says he gets at least 100k more in loot then I do. Is this possible? I've tried to trick him and say I got more then what is offered and he still says his is 100k more so I know he's lying, but wasn't sure about actually getting the same for hitting the same person!

Comment: It depends who you attack

Comment: For those of you in the close vote queue, I play this game and what he is asking is fairly straightforward and answerable. I think it should remain open

Answer (score 0):

Check in war details which targets your friend has attacked. There is *War Win Bonus* for each target. So you could could figure out whether or not your friend is lying.

Answer (score 0):

If a person is a higher rank than you in war, they will get the same or lower loot from any base they attack as you would. Therefore you can simply check which bases they attacked and see the what you would have gotten from attacking those bases. This is the max you clan mate could have gotten from attacking those bases, so you can easily tell if they are telling the truth by comparing that value to what you earned.

Now, it is possible that he got 100k more in loot than you, as different bases award different loot values for successful attacks against them. If you were to attack 2 lower ranked bases, and they attacked 2 higher ranked bases, it is very possible they got 100k+ more loot from the war than you did.